# jQuery traversing on the same level

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

Example of my code:

```
<section id="reports">

  <div class="report">
    <div class="report-expand">MORE</div> <!-- this one is clicked -->
  </div>
  <ul class="report-moreinfo"></ul> <!-- I want to select this one -->

  <div class="report">
    <div class="report-expand">MORE</div>
  </div>
  <ul class="report-moreinfo"></ul>
  <div class="report">
    <div class="report-expand">MORE</div>
  </div>
  <ul class="report-moreinfo"></ul>

</section>
```

This is part of my jQuery:

```
$('.report').on('click', '.report-expand', function(e) {
  // $(this) === '.report-expand'
  $(this).closest('.report') // now what..?
}
```

How do I finish the traversing to properly select the `ul.report-moreinfo` that follows the `.report` I currently have selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('.report').next();
```

since the list is the **next sibling**. If you want to get the previous sibling, you would use `.prev`.
More info: http://api.jquery.com/next/, http://api.jquery.com/prev/.

[Here is a list of all traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Since you bound the event handler to the `.report` element anyway, you can also make use of [`event.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) instead of `$(this).closest(...)`:

```
$(event.delegateTarget).next();
```

Comment: I ended up using `$(event.delegateTarget).next();` - thank you! I had actually tried `$(this).closest().next();` before but there was a .remove() earlier in the code that messed up the behavior which made me think I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
  $(this).parent().next()
```

`$(this).parent()` will give `report`  div

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(this).parent().next();
```

Using `.parent()` is preferable to using `.closest()` for performance reasons as long as `.report-expand` is always the direct child of `.report`.

**Edit:** Having reviewed other answers, I think `$(event.delegateTarget).next();`, which Felix Kling first suggested, is the most efficient query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.next([selector])](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** function. Something like this:

```
$(this).closest('.report').next('ul.report-moreinfo');
```

But since `div.report` is the parent of `div.report-expand` you can just do:

```
$(this).parent().next('ul.report-moreinfo');
```

or use the delegateTarget provided by the click event callback:

```
$(e.delegateTarget).next('ul.report-moreinfo');
```